# Selenium Python ChromeDriver crashing with basic test script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

So I have installed python3.8, selenium 4.16 and chromedriver on my web server with root ssh access. I can run chromedriver in terminal, looking good.
When I try a simple python script it crashes with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium-4.16.0-py3.8.egg/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium-4.16.0-py3.8.egg/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 84, in driver_location
    browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sel.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium-4.16.0-py3.8.egg/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium-4.16.0-py3.8.egg/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium-4.16.0-py3.8.egg/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 40, in get_path
    msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'
```

I have tried this very basic test script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.8
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.python.org")
print(driver.title)
```

It looks like it cannot find something, tries to check "capabilities" but they obviously don't exist for something "unknown". Instead of checking for type and existance of appropriate item, it throws a message which doesn't help – I consider this very bad programming. Anyway - does anyone have an idea what this is?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.python.org")
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Welcome to Python.org
```

Comment: I have chromedriver in PATH. but have tried to use complete path as well: no difference, same crash message

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome()
@DønerM. try like this. It will automatically download chrome driver and run.

Comment: unfortunately not, it throws the same message but adds "Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https..." - this page says chromedriver has to be in PATH. it is. I can run it from anywhere. this doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: @DønerM., I am using Linux . My modied code snipped worked.

Comment: I am using a remote Linux webserver. I have installed ChromLinux64 as well (don't know where to put it, added it to PATH just in case), but I am unsure wether this is needed or not. no installation guider or tutorial mentions it.